# Is my boot process normal? It takes 50 seconds boot

Tags: boot, performance, fsck

Here's my boot.log

```
resume: libgcrypt version: 1.5.0
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
/dev/sda5: clean, 668102/3276800 files, 4449436/13107200 blocks
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
uhome: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: clean, 3030/74592 files, 200601/297200 blocks (check in 2 mounts)
uhome: clean, 282203/2621440 files, 8705593/10485760 blocks (check after next mount)
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
 * Starting AppArmor profiles       [170G 
[164G[ OK ]
 * Setting sensors limits       [170G 
[164G[ OK ]
Invalidating stale software suspend images... done.
 * Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon[164G[ OK ]
Starting DECnet... * Starting network connection manager[164G[ OK ]
done.
 * Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay[164G[ OK ]
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility[164G[ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility[164G[ OK ]
 * Starting Bumblebee supporting nVidia Optimus cards[164G[ OK ]
 * Starting LightDM Display Manager[164G[ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages[164G[ OK ]
 * Starting ACPI daemon[164G[ OK ]
 * Starting anac(h)ronistic cron[164G[ OK ]
 * Starting deferred execution scheduler[164G[ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon[164G[ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation[164G[[31mfail[39;49m]
 * Stopping anac(h)ronistic cron[164G[ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon[164G[ OK ]
```

Contents of fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=d30f09f8-9580-4a6b-ac31-f69116793f9f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=28309a48-2171-4784-8093-d0e5ca40e6de /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=4d7ee3e9-bf26-483d-af6e-efcd883126d0 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=f1a123f0-c81d-4f0a-9d5c-6780cbf8b9dc none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Here's dmesg log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/826319/'

The dmesg log shows quite a bit bump after 6 seconds, it waits too much before starting again at 24th second.

Output of `fdisk -l` and `mount` : http://paste.ubuntu.com/826397/

I have disabled almost all services which I can, but it still takes 50 seconds to boot. While booting with Live USB, it hardly takes 25 seconds.

The boot process stops for about 20 seconds at "resume libcrypt version" line. And those fscks are performed at every boot. Are those fscks necessary?

**EDIT**: Bootchart
[image: bootchart]

Comment: please add the utput of dmesg short after booting into your initial posting!

Comment: ah and fsck = file system check - should not be necessary at every boot time. My boot progress consumes approx. 19 sec but with a very fast HDD (1500MB / sec)

Comment: @MichaelK I have added dmesg log. I know about fsck, but i don't get the one that actually checks file system after 25/30 mounts. It just shows this "fsck from util-linux...' and those 'recovering journal' logs which is where it stops most of the time.

Comment: @fossfreedom I have added the contents of fstab.

Comment: Recovering journal logs implies that something failed in writing files to your hard drive. Either a bad shut down or a dying hard drive could cause this. Does this happen repeatedly? Have you tried running a full fsck from a live cd (with drive unmounted!!!) to fix it?

Comment: @maco It seems to that recovering journal comes quite often in my boot log. And well this is new laptop and I don't think it might be a problem with hdd. I'll do fsck from live CD then post the updated logs.

Comment: @Muneeb don't assume new systems come with brand new parts.  Many systems manufacturers use refurbished parts to replace system components for new machines, so the chance you get parts that are DODOA (Dead or Dying On Arrival) exists.

Comment: @Muneeb Additionally, sometimes parts are defective straight from the factory (hence the typical 1 year hardware warranty most computers and parts come with). Also, you're comparing the boot time of solid state drive (your Live USB) to that of a platter/disk based drive (your standard hard drive). Solid state will always be worlds faster, because there are no moving parts. On a side note (and out of curiosity), why are you worried about a sub-minute boot time, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The normal booting time is 40s (including BIOS). You might have some "not so good" hardware which causes this problem. Also you must have kept many things on boot and installed many packages. But you need not worry.

Comment: Can you provide a citation, or more information, for the claim that booting usually takes 40 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You might try starting Terminal and then entering the code below, modified for your circumstances/ needs.

```
sudo tune2fs -c 50 /dev/hda1
```

The 50 should make the system execute fsck every 50 boots. 50~100 is deemed usual.
The hda1 might be hda1, hda2, hda3...   or sda1, sda2, sda3... depending on your setup.

You'd get more info by entering `man tune2fs`. The **down arrow** takes you down through the manpage.